# How to use pandas dataframe as condition for other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

Say I have dataframe A:

```
      A B  C
lower 1 0 -5
upper 2 2  0
```

and dataframe B:

```
     A  B  C
sa   5  1 -2
sb   3  0  2
sc   1 -5  1
```

How can I use dataframe A as a condition for dataframe B, so that df B's cells are within the `upper` and `lower` values of df A. The ideal output is this: (first cell is explanatory)

```
     A                     B      C
sa   (5>=1)&(5<=2)=False   True   True
sb   False                 True   False
sc   True                  False  False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain mask with compare selected rows by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) in `A` with [`DataFrame.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ge.html) and [`DataFrame.le`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.le.html) by `&` for bitwise `AND`:

Notice - columns names have to match in both `DataFrame`s.

```
df = B.ge(A.loc['lower']) & B.le(A.loc['upper'])
#alternative
#df = (B>= A.loc['lower']) & (B <= A.loc['upper'])
print (df)
        A      B      C
sa  False   True   True
sb  False   True  False
sc   True  False  False
```

Comment: wow thanks that works great! Now this I could have never come up by myself, so I'll take the opportunity and ask you, how do you become so good, cause I want to get good especially at pandas and I cant seem to make it. Do you read the whole documentation? What should my steps be, apart from practice, to become this good? Thanks again!

Comment: @Mario - for me working 4 years of coding, the best daily. After some time I also study docs (and better understand it, fistly it was like foreign language, not understand it.)

Comment: thanks for replying, looks like I have a long way ahead!